# Populating embedded documents to local references in MongoDB / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am struggeling with population of references to nested documents. I tried a lot of solutions that i found on StackOverflow and Google but i just don't get it to work.

In short: There are **Venues**. Venues can define business **hours** for various **Seasons**. For example: "The swimming pool is open from July 1st to September 15th on saturdays and sundays from 9 to 5".

So here are the (simplified) **schemas**:

```
var SeasonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    from: Date,
    to: Date
});

mongoose.model("Venue.seasons", SeasonSchema);

var HourSeasonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    seasonref: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Venue.seasons'},
    "1" : DaySchema,
    "2" : DaySchema,
    "3" : DaySchema,
    "4" : DaySchema,
    "5" : DaySchema,
    "6" : DaySchema,
    "7" : DaySchema
});

var VenueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, default: ''},
    description: {type: String, default: ''},        
    images: [mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed],
    address: AddressSchema,
    flags: {
        toddlers: Number
    },
    seasons: [SeasonSchema],
    hours: [HourSeasonSchema]
});
```

This is my **query**:

```
Venue.find(query)
  .populate({
    path: "hours",
    populate: {
      path: "seasonref",
      model: "Venue.seasons" //tried with and without model property
    }
  }).exec((err, result) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }      
    // make further use of result        
  });
```

This is an **example result** that i get from my queries:

```
{ _id: 5a0016882694921349cb8ee1,
    address: { ... },
    seasons:
    [ { name: 'Ganzjährig',
       from: 2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
       to: 2017-12-30T23:00:00.000Z,
       _id: 5a00184c2694921349cb8eef }, //REFERENCING THIS DOCUMENT
   [length]: 1 ],
    __v: 4,
    hours:
    [ { '1':
        { opened: true,
            opening: 2017-11-06T10:00:00.000Z,
            closing: 2017-11-06T22:00:00.000Z,
            pausestart: 2017-11-06T12:00:00.000Z,
            pauseend: 2017-11-06T13:00:00.000Z,
            _id: 5a001ee62694921349cb8f2f },
        '2':
        { opened: true,
            opening: 2017-11-06T10:00:00.000Z,
            closing: 2017-11-06T22:00:00.000Z,
            pausestart: 2017-11-06T12:00:00.000Z,
            pauseend: 2017-11-06T13:00:00.000Z,
            _id: 5a001ee62694921349cb8f2e },
        ...,
        _id: 5a001ee62694921349cb8f28,
        seasonref: 5a00184c2694921349cb8eef //SHOULD BE POPULATED INTO HERE
        }
    ],
    pricecategories: [ [length]: 0 ],
    ...
}
```

This is an **example result** that i'd like to get from the query:

```
{ _id: 5a0016882694921349cb8ee1,
    address: { ... },
    __v: 4,
     seasons:
       [ { name: 'Ganzjährig',
         from: 2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
         to: 2017-12-30T23:00:00.000Z,
        _id: 5a00184c2694921349cb8eef },
       [length]: 1 ],
    hours:
    [ { '1':
        { opened: true,
            opening: 2017-11-06T10:00:00.000Z,
            closing: 2017-11-06T22:00:00.000Z,
            pausestart: 2017-11-06T12:00:00.000Z,
            pauseend: 2017-11-06T13:00:00.000Z,
            _id: 5a001ee62694921349cb8f2f },
        '2':
        { opened: true,
            opening: 2017-11-06T10:00:00.000Z,
            closing: 2017-11-06T22:00:00.000Z,
            pausestart: 2017-11-06T12:00:00.000Z,
            pauseend: 2017-11-06T13:00:00.000Z,
            _id: 5a001ee62694921349cb8f2e },
        ...,
        _id: 5a001ee62694921349cb8f28,
        seasonref: {
          name: 'Ganzjährig',
          from: 2016-12-31T23:00:00.000Z,
          to: 2017-12-30T23:00:00.000Z,
          _id: 5a00184c2694921349cb8eef }
        }
    ],
    pricecategories: [ [length]: 0 ],
    ...
}
```

No matter how i configure everything (with or without a model, with old or new population method) i don't get the nested document to be populated into the result.

Comment: Try naming your schema `Venue_seasons` instead of `Venue.seasons` and tell me what happens. What is your collection name in MongoDB, when you register schema named `Venue.seasons` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I renamed the model like you suggested. Nothing changed. Everything stays the same. Actually there is no collection created for the model in the mongoDB anyway. It is only used as a nested schema in this document.

Comment: My quick guess would be that it's not possible to populate subdocuments without own collection to the schema of which they're not subdocuments, but it's only a guess. Tried to google a bit, but with no strong result. Your syntax's fine, all seems good, and I can't see any other problems either.

Comment: If i completey externalize the subdocuments into their own collections so that they are no subdocuments but just referenced documents everything works as expected. But i think it is less performant than having the data in the documents directly.

Comment: Yes, it is, it's one more mongo call, to their own collection.